# Como evitar o Avanço de papel

Tags: c#, .net, impressão

Olá, estou utilizando uma impressora térmica não fiscal da Engeworks para imprimir comprovantes de pagamentos, estou utilizando o driver Generic Text Only.

O problema é que ela imprime os comprovantes como se fossem páginas inteiras e eu queria q ela só imprimisse o necessário, terminou a impressão já parar de puxar papel e cortar.

Tem como ajustar isso nas configurações?

Obrigado.

Comment: Já tentou alterar o tamanho do papel desta impressora `Generic Text Only`?

Comment: Fez algum código? Tem documentação da impressão?

Comment: Você está fazendo em qual linguagem?

Comment: Você está enviando de que forma os dados para a impressora, por relatório ou diretamente como string?